# How can I build simple secure web service with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, security

Purpose of this web service is to server html/javascript/css/binary data inside simple XML document (or are there better suggestion for fromat? Could JSON be used for this kind of web service?) and requests requesting this data would be simple XML request containing 10-100 objects. By simple I mean not too complex framework that requires a lot of memory and classes. By secure I mean service that couldn't be easily abused by hackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP over SSL, possibly using WS-Security to ensure identity (or alternatively using a servlet filter to do authentication based on credentials in the HTTP headers), does that quite nicely.

No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [REST](http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341d3df553ef012875f312f9970c-pi) with https. Take a look at [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) and the [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html). REST also offers 'native' support for different response representations. No need to wrap them inside XML.

Answer (score 1):

To me the simplest is Soap, Java automatically generates the WSDL and do all the XML stuff for you. You can use it on top of SSL secure transfers to add the security layer that you need. It is not *unbreakable*, but at least the data is not transfered in plain text.

Regards!